# Algorithm from folderstring to correct folderstructure in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of data which is a string of folders:

```
var data = [{ name: "/X" }, { name: "/X/Y" }, { name: "/X2" },  { name: "/X2/Z" }, { name: "/X/k" }]
```

For a component to display this items I need them sorted nested like these:

```
var data = [{ name: "/X", sub: [{ name: "/Y" }, { name: "/k" }]}, { name: "/X2" }, sub: [{ name: "/Z" }] }]
```

These items are just examples, the item count is 1000+ and the nested items can be unlimited too.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: What specifically is tripping you up? Seems like each entry is a set of keys separated by `/`, so for each you'd want to split it up, see if each "directory" value has an entry in the "file table" (say, an object), if not, create it, and walk that file table for each value. Code length should be pretty short.

Comment: The depth doesn't make any difference; it's the same code. Chop the keys down as you walk; when you're out of keys, you're done. (Noting that the terminal case may or may not need to be handled specially depending on whether or not you need to differentiate between "directories" and "files".)

Comment: Lol. That's not how SO works. Perhaps write it in C# first then translate it to JS?

Comment: What if one folder has many subs? How the result will look like? Please add to your question to `data` new element: `{ name: "/X/Z" }` and change the desired result. Thanks

Comment: @Anton Thank you, I have edit the example

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper The "problem with me" is your misunderstanding of the purpose of exercises like this. It is neither toxic, nor helpful, to hand out answers when it's a problem explicitly designed to make you think. Handing out an answer, instead of pointing in the right direction (in multiple steps if necessary) thus *leading* you to a solution answer deprives you of the purpose of the exercise. Now you'll hand in the answer knowing that you didn't do the work, and anything gained from this is a small portion of what *could* have been gained. YMMV.

Comment: (Noting also that without any solution attempt provided, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions, it falls into an "incomplete question" category.)

Comment: And offering to *pay* someone to do your homework is unethical, btw.

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper If you look at the links I provided you will see (a) your question was incomplete and showed no effort, and (b) homework *in particular* should include evidence of a good faith effort. You *said* you worked on it, and I have no reason to believe you're lying, but nobody can *see* that you worked on it. Maybe you were a line of code away from an answer. Maybe you weren't. We'll never know, and *you'll* never know if you could have solved it yourself. Maybe for *you* "just give me the code" is enough; if so, sorry to hear that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with `forEach` and `reduce` methods and use one object to keep track of level based on the current part of the name property value.

```js
const data = [{ name: "/X" }, { name: "/X/Y" }, { name: "/X2" },  { name: "/X2/Z" }, {name: '/X/K/1'}, {name: '/X/K/2'}]


const result = []
const level = {result}

data.forEach(({ name, ...rest }) => {
  name.split('/').filter(Boolean).reduce((r, k) => {
    if (!r[k]) {
      r[k] = { result: [] }
      r.result.push({
        name: `/${k}`,
        sub: r[k].result
      })
    }

    return r[k]
  }, level)
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: That seems todo the trick... I dont understand that code, but thank you very very much

Answer (score 0):

Using `reduce()` and `Map()`

```js
var data = [{ name: "/X" }, { name: "/X/Y" }, { name: "/X2" },  { name: "/X2/Z" }, { name: "/X/k" }]

var res = data.reduce((a, i) => {
  let s = i.name.match(/\/\w+/g) || []
  if (a.has(s[0])) {
    let path = a.get(s[0])
    i.name = s[1]
    path.sub = path.sub || []
    path.sub.push(i)
  } else {
    a.set(i.name, i)
  }
  return a
}, new Map())

console.log([...res.values()])
```

Comment: Seems your algorythms is not working totaly: When you have more subitems then the first length (e.g /x/K/1/z and /x/K/2/Y) then the result will be totaly wrong =(